# SASS nesting imported styles to create compound selectors

Tags: sass

## What I am looking for

I have a scss file with that I am using across my site.

```
// common.scss
.red {
    background: red;
}

.green {
    background: green ;
}
```

In another scss file I would like to add these common styles to an element which will have a class: `.filter` and which are inside of a wrapper class: `.wrapper`. I am looking for this to be the resulting css of this new file:

```
// css
.wrapper > .filter.red {
  background: red;
}
.wrapper > .filter.green {
  background: green;
}
```

Also, please be aware that I cannot alter common.scss because it is used in other style sheets.

---

## What I have tried

#### Attempt #1

For my scss file I did this:

```
// new_element.scss
.wrapper > {
    .filter {
      @import "./common.scss";
    }
}
```

But that produces:

```
// css
.wrapper > .filter .red {
  background: red;
}
.wrapper > .filter .green {
  background: green;
}
```

*Note the difference between `.filter .red` and `.filter.red`*

#### Attempt #2

I also tried:

```
// new_element.scss
.wrapper > {
    .filter & {
      @import "./common.scss";
    }
}
```

But that produces:

```
// css
.filter .wrapper > .red {
  background: red;
}
.filter .wrapper > .green {
  background: green;
}
```

#### Attempt #3

and this:

```
// new_element.scss
.wrapper {
    > .filter & {
      @import "./common.scss";
    }
}
```

produces:

```
// css
> .filter .wrapper .red {
  background: red;
}
> .filter .wrapper .green {
  background: green;
}
```

---

## The Question

Is there any way to get my desired output, aka is there a way to make a compound class selector combining `.filter` with other selectors which are within an external file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear, but I'd try either `&.foo` or `&.bar`:

```
// new_element.scss
&.foo {
  @import './common.scss';
}
```

or

```
// common.scss
&.bar {
    background: red;
}
```

Before, you'd tried `.foo & {`, which was really close, but it'd produce `.foo .bar {` instead of `.foo.bar {`, which is what I think you wanted.

If you remove the space between `.foo` and `&`, it'll return `.foo.bar`

Comment: Ive updated my post, its a bit more complicated now... but hopefully also a little more clear. Your first suggestion: `&.foo` doesnt work. Your second suggestion would work.... however it would require altering common.scss... which I cannot do because it is being imported and used by other style sheets. Altering it would cause the other instances to break.